# Starting an Intent to Launch an app to Background in Android

Tags: android, background, android-intent, launch

I'm using Wikitude API 1.1 as an AR viewer in my application. The problem with Wikitude, if I haven't launched the actual Wikitude application since the phone's bootup, I will get a NullPointerException everytime I start my own application.

So I figure if I can start my app first and them check if Wikitude is installed and or running. If it's not installed, go to market n download. If it's not running, then we should run it straight to background so that my app doesn't loose its focus.

```
    // Workaround for Wikitude
    this.WIKITUDE_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.wikitude";
    PackageManager pacMan = Poligamy.this.getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo pacInfo = pacMan.getPackageInfo(this.WIKITUDE_PACKAGE_NAME, pacMan.GET_SERVICES);
        Log.i("CheckWKTD", "Wikitude is Installed");
        ActivityManager aMan = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningApps = aMan.getRunningAppProcesses();
        int numberOfApps = runningApps.size();

        for(int i=0; i<numberOfApps; i++) {
            if(runningApps.get(i).processName.equals(this.WIKITUDE_PACKAGE_NAME)) {
                this.WIKITUDE_RUNNING = 1;
                Log.i("CheckWKTD", "Wikitude is Running");
            }
        }
        if(this.WIKITUDE_RUNNING == 0) {
            Log.i("CheckWKTD", "Wikitude is NOT Running");
            /*final Intent wIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            wIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.wikitude", 
                    "com.mobilizy.wikitudepremium.initial.Splash");
            wIntent.setComponent(cn);
            wIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
            startActivityIfNeeded(wIntent, 0);*/
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.i("CheckWKTD", "Wikitude is NOT Installed");
        e.printStackTrace();
        //finish();
    }
```

The part I block commented is the intent to start Wikitude. But I always failed in restricting Wikitude to background. Any help? Thanks before.

Best,
Tista

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "run it straight to background".

I would focus on fixing your `NullPointerException` by contacting WIKITUDE and figuring out why you are getting it if their app has not yet been run.